# module that synchronize prestashop 1.6 with erp

Tags: php, web-services, api, prestashop-1.6

I am a new programmer and don´t have experience. I need to create a module(or class) (in php) that synchronize the prestashop web service to my erp. I just activated the web service and works properly (myshop/api or myshop/api/customers e.g), but I don´t know what is next step. 
I need that my module detect any changes in prestashop and send/update the erp.
Please help.Thx

Comment: it's off-topic on SO. Here, we can help you only on precise technical issue. We can't help you to know how to do something, or method to achieve goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can either with hooks know that information has been changed, and so triggered an update, or went through spots crons.

On the other hand it is necessary to see what your ERP is and how it can be contacted, we have already treated several ERP with Prestashop, and each ERP has its constraints.

You should therefore learn more about the ERP and the information you want to update.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks. I am with that: find out how action hooks work.I will ask more things when after find out that.